# Is there a simple way to send a two dimensional array in JSON?

Tags: json, multidimensional-array

I am building a collection of board games playable through a web app running .NET and C# on the backend. I want to store the game state in a database to maybe allow 2 players.  I have already written the gameplay into the code. I am learning frontend and controllers and I want to host these games in webapp format. Unfortunately, it does not seem json cannot handle gameboard[][] as easily as C# can. Is there a simple way to send those back to the controller? I could format it like this but typing all this out for a 10x10 or bigger board is not optimal:

```
{
    "board":
    [
        [
            "red"//[0][0]
        ],
        [
            "black"//[0][1]
        ],
        [
            null//[0][2]
        ]
        // ... and so on
    ],
    [
        [
            null//[1][0]
        ],
        [
            "black"//[1][1]
        ],
        [
            null//[1][2]
        ]
        // ... and so on
    ],
    [
        [
            null//[2][0]
        ],
        [
            "black"//[2][1]
        ],
        [
            null//[2][2]
        ]
        // ... and so on
    ]
} // this is invalid json, but i dont see why
```

I have looked at other similar questions about 2D arrays, but I cannot figure out the best way to send using JSON.

Also:
It may be possible instead to just send an update to the board for each piece that is placed. I may need to look into sending that instead. Thanks for reading and any help!

Edit: changed JSON to fit answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra set of {} around each inner array.  Do it like:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4]
]
```

Comment: is it possible to have normal key-value pairs or other types of objects as the contents of these array indices? Thanks for your answer! Also will this be accessible like `json.board[i][j]`?

Comment: Sure.  The values in the array can be any valid JSON value.  That includes objects.  The full object including the {} would go where one of the numbers is right now.